# How do I set the scroll bar of a div on top?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a div with a long text, it shows the vertical scroll bar. I show-hide this div with Jquery so it looks like a popup.

When it's hidden the scroll remains at the place the user put it, so when it shows up againg the scroll is at the same place, I want it to be on top every time it shows up again.

So the question is: How do I set the scroll bar of a div on top with jquery??

CODE:

```
<div class="scroll_div" align="justify">
   <p align="center">
      Text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text
      .............
      .............
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiiddle for this or share your jquery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jQuery, just set `.scrollTop(0)`

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ka8vm/

Comment: It only works if I put the code before hiding the <div>. It's fine for me, but why can´t I set the scroll once the div is hidden??

Comment: @MarcoTck if it makes sense, when a element is hidden, it doesn't have a height anymore, thus no scroll position either, so you can't set it at that point. If you would like to do that, you can set `visibility:hidden` instead of `display: none`, although you won't be able to use jquery's `show()` and `hide()` functions.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, despite the solution it's good to know why things occur.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#div').scrollTop(0)` to move the scroller to the top

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#div').scrollTop(0);
    $('#div').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6hStd/)